# How to create text file based on date in c#

Tags: c#, string, text-files, file-handling

I have a text file which is getting populated continuously from the server data.Here is the sample data present in the text file..

```
1/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
1/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
1/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
2/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
2/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
2/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
3/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
3/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23 
3/1/2014   234  34  456788889989 23
```

Here is my code to create text file..

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\datewise.txt", "");
```

Here for every date there is lot of data present as row.Now as soon as date changes i have to create a text file and copy all the data from sample text file to the newly created text file.How to achieve this?

Comment: Any code snippets what you do so far ?

Comment: what is sample text file here, please elaborate more it is unclear

Comment: @Aaron the data that is present in the post is the sample text file.

Comment: ok, one more query you don't know how to copy one text file to another or you don't know what to do when date changes ?

Comment: Can you not get the server to name the datewise.txt file something like 20140122.txt and create it if it doesn't exist? There may be some locking issues that you might have to deal with if the server tries to write while its creating the new file. But you'd have this problem at some point anyway as the file cannot just grow and grow

Comment: @Aaron sir i dont know how to create text file and copy all the data of the previous date into the newly created text file..From the sample text file last date is 3/1/2014 as soon as 4/1/2014 date data starts getting dumped i have to write all data relevant to 3/1/2014 in the newly created text file

Comment: Something like this you mean? 
`string strDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string FileToCopy = "d:\\datewise.txt";
string NewCopy = strPath + strDateTime;
if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) == true) {
 System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy);
 return strDateTime;
} else {
 return null;
}`

Comment: @drewlander i want this as well as all the data relevant to that date be copied into newly created text file

Comment: for my edification, can you expand on the original file? does it get truncated or is it running?  You only want to copy certain rows from the source file to the new file?  Im just not very clear on that.

Comment: @drewlander i want to copy only that rows which has the same date as of the text file name.Suppose text file is  3/1/2014.text then i want to copy only that rows which contains 3/1/2014 date

Comment: sounds like you want a regex to match the begining of the line, if it matches grab the line and copy it to the file with the corresponding date.  Is that correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45864/discussion-between-adi-and-drewlander)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;

    string pattern = "^3/1/2014.*"; 
    string strPath = new string("c:\\"); 
    string strDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"); 
    string FileToCopy = "c:\\regexTest.txt"; 
    string NewCopy = strPath + strDateTime + ".txt"; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(""); 
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) == true) { 
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileToCopy); 
    foreach (string line in lines) { 
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, pattern)) { 
    sb.Append(line + System.Environment.NewLine); 
    } 
    } 
    } 

    if (sb.Length > 0) { 
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(NewCopy, sb.ToString); 
    }
```

Comment: Clean it up and tailor to your needs, but I tested it with your sample data and it works as you explained your requirements.